# Suggestions for Hindu books regarding political philosophy

Tags: manu-smriti, book-recommendation

I am wanting to read and learn about Hindu political philosophy. I know about the "Laws of Manu", but I am unsure of any other books that relate, I would like to read similar things such as the famous "The Prince" by Machiavelli, but obviously with the Hindu perspective.

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to post the question but I would really appreciate book/scriptural suggestions, if you could specify the specific translator/writer of the book also (I read in English) that would be very helpful (a lot of the western translators seem to put their own Hinduphobic spin on the translations).

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you are seeking something like Arthashastra by Chanakya.

Comment: @Just_Do_It YES! Books like these are exactly what I'm looking for, do you have a suggestion for any specific edition I should read? Thanks!

Comment: try this one out https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1769362.The_Arthashastra

Comment: Thank you !, if you have any others , please do send :)